# Calling Python from C++, how to get rid of the `-Wstrict-prototypes` warning?

Tags: python, c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I am trying to call the python function from C++. I wrote a simple *main.cpp* file and and *helloworld.py* as the following:

**main.cpp:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");

    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule( "helloworld" );

    PyObject *pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "say_hello_world");

    PyEval_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);

    Py_Initialize();
}
```

**helloworld.py:**

```
def say_hello_world():
    print( "Hello World from Python" )
```

I compile the program with:

> g++ `python-config --cflags` main.cpp `python-config --ldflags` -o main

And as a result, everything works fine except that I get the following warning:

> cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

What's the cause of this? Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry if I messed up your command line. The backticks should be used only to indicate `code` - I had trouble in guessing what you meant, and that's what I ended up with. Please fix it if it's not accurate.

Comment: @BartoszKP Those backticks are necessary in the command line. `python-config --cflags` and `python-config --ldflags` simply mean add the configuration for python library. For example, if we are using OpenCV libs, we will add something like `opencv-config --cflags` and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a script `gccflags-filter` that would filter out flags inappropriate for a given language. For example

```
  python-config --cflags | gccflags-filter --lang=c++
```

The list of flags can be taken from the documentation.

If you need a stopgap measure for your particular problem now, consider something like

```
 g++ `python-config --cflags | sed s/-Wstrict-prototypes//`
```

Comment: ...and please file a bug report, so people can fix that script.